# In App Messaging - UI sdk - crash on release build

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am new to Salesforce sdk. I am using In app messaging UI sdk to implement chat feature within app and it's working in debug build. When i run on release build it crash with attached stacks trace.

I have separate module for chat that was built in 2018 and now we are utilizing that to implement chat feature using salesforce ([inAppMessaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-in-app/guide/android-ui-sdk.html))UI sdk.

Error pointing to this Salesforce class [RichLinkImage (salesforce-async-messaging.github.io)](https://salesforce-async-messaging.github.io/messaging-in-app-android/messaging-inapp-network/com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.component.attachment/-file-asset/-image-asset/-rich-link-image/index.html)

I have chat bubble in activity using fragment within that creating viewmodel to configure salesforce. I am also using obfuscation tool on release build. So I am not sure what is causing this error.

**Logs**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property for required constructor parameter #0 p0 of fun
                                                                                                    `<init>`(kotlin.String, kotlin.String?, kotlin.String?, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String?): com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.component.attachment.FileAsset.ImageAsset.RichLinkImage
                                                                                                    for class com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.component.attachment.FileAsset$ImageAsset$RichLinkImage image
                                                                                                    for class com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.format.StaticContentFormat$RichLinkFormat
                                                                                                    for interface com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.format.StaticContentFormat content
                                                                                                    for class com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.Message$StaticContentMessage
                                                                                                    for interface com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.Message abstractMessage
                                                                                                    for class com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.EntryPayload$MessagePayload
                                                                                                    for interface com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.EntryPayload
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$ɩ.isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(SourceFile:389)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:158)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.format.StaticContentFormat_RichLinkFormatJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:28)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(SourceFile:588)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:200)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:106)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:75)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.adapters.PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:216)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.Message_StaticContentMessageJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:41)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(SourceFile:588)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:200)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:106)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:75)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.adapters.PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:216)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.EntryPayload_MessagePayloadJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:32)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(SourceFile:588)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:200)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:106)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:75)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.adapters.PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:216)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:106)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:80)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.internal.api.rest.RestService.<init>(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.internal.api.rest.RestService.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
2024-01-31 14:30:43.444 31118-31118 AndroidRuntime          usap64                               E      at com.salesforce.android.smi.network.internal.api.rest.RestService$Companion.create$default(SourceFile:339)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.core.internal.ServiceLocator.restService(SourceFile:56)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.core.internal.InternalCoreClient$Companion.create(SourceFile:171)
                                                                                                        at com.salesforce.android.smi.core.internal.InternalCoreClientFactory.create(SourceFile:31)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragmentViewModel.coreClient(SourceFile:130)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragmentViewModel.registerHiddenPreChatValuesProvider(SourceFile:54)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragmentViewModel.setupMessaging(SourceFile:70)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragmentViewModel.resetMessagingConfig(SourceFile:46)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragmentViewModel.<init>(SourceFile:25)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.VMFactory.create(SourceFile:143)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(SourceFile:83)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(SourceFile:184)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(SourceFile:150)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ParentChatbotFragment.onCreate(SourceFile:96)
                                                                                                        at com.manulife.chatbot.fragments.ChatbotFragment.onCreate(SourceFile:30)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(SourceFile:3094)
                                                                                                        at o.ѳ.BuiltInFictitiousFunctionClassFactory(SourceFile:504)
                                                                                                        at o.ѳ.getPredefinedCategories(SourceFile:268)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.CipherOutputStream(SourceFile:1943)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.CipherOutputStream(SourceFile:1839)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(SourceFile:1782)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.setIconSize(SourceFile:3042)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.CipherOutputStream(SourceFile:2952)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(SourceFile:263)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:350)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(SourceFile:251)
                                                                                                        at ca.manulife.MobileBanking.CalligraphyActivity.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1525)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8030)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8068)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property for required constructor parameter #0 p0 of fun
                                                                                                    `<init>`(kotlin.String, kotlin.String?, kotlin.String?, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String?): com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.entryPayload.message.component.attachment.FileAsset.ImageAsset.RichLinkImage
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:312)
                                                                                                        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:146)
```

Comment: Do you have an open support case? Also, if this works in debug, but not in production, I would check your obfuscation rules. I'm not the expert on this SDK, but this sure smells like it's solvable with a `keep` rule.

Comment: Thank you @Bill for quick response. 

I tried adding `keep com.salesforce.android.smi.network.data.domain.conversationEntry.*` but issue is still there. So I will try turning off the obfuscation and generate release build to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: The `keep` statement is going to be more complex than you've listed, and why not just keep all of the salesforce stuff as-is? Note, I'm not saying this is your problem. Just smells like it :)

Comment: My teammate found temporary solution `-keepparameternames`

The Salesforce SDK is using the Moshi json library but without any annotations to preserve field names. Moshi is using kotlin-reflect to match constructor parameters to the json entries, and, predictably, throwing because the names do not match. Interestingly, this seems to only affect classes with non-property args, eg
`class MyClass(value: Int)` instead of `val value`

Comment: You should open a support case, raise the question, and offer the solution you've found. Probably something they can add to their proguard rules file that will prevent this from happening.